# keypad popup blocks view of application in delphi xe8 Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I tried this [example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE5/en/FMX.Mobile.ScrollableForm_Sample_%28Delphi%29). But it doesn't work if the edit field has 'password' property set to true. Any idea how to make it work with password edit fields?

Comment: Please add your code in the question itself. Outside links can always break and when that happens, your question will become useless to any other future readers which may have the same problem. Please also clarify what exactly you mean with "doesn't work"? Is there any error? What is the expected behaviour and what does it do instead? Read the [How to ask FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample for what you are trying to do. Simply put all your controls inside `lyVKMain`.

```
object frmBaseForm: TfrmBaseForm
  OnFocusChanged = FormFocusChanged
  OnVirtualKeyboardShown = FormVirtualKeyboardShown
  OnVirtualKeyboardHidden = FormVirtualKeyboardHidden
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object vsVKScrollBox: TVertScrollBox
    Align = Contents
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 2
    Viewport.Width = 640.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 480.000000000000000000
    object lyVKMain: TLayout
      Align = Client
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TabOrder = 0
    end
  end
end
```

And the unit file...

```
unit uForm;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Types,
  System.UITypes,
  System.Classes,
  System.Variants,
  FMX.Types,
  FMX.Controls,
  FMX.Forms,
  FMX.Graphics,
  FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Layouts;

type
  TfrmBaseForm = class(TForm)
    vsVKScrollBox: TVertScrollBox;
    lyVKMain: TLayout;
    procedure FormFocusChanged(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormVirtualKeyboardHidden(Sender: TObject; KeyboardVisible: Boolean; const Bounds: TRect);
    procedure FormVirtualKeyboardShown(Sender: TObject; KeyboardVisible: Boolean; const Bounds: TRect);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    FKBBounds: TRectF;
    FNeedOffset: Boolean;
    procedure CalcContentBoundsProc(Sender: TObject; var ContentBounds: TRectF);
    procedure RestorePosition;
    procedure UpdateKBBounds;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

var
  frmBaseForm: TfrmBaseForm;

implementation

uses
  System.Math;

{$R *.fmx}
{ TfrmBaseForm }

procedure TfrmBaseForm.CalcContentBoundsProc(Sender: TObject; var ContentBounds: TRectF);
begin
  if FNeedOffset and (FKBBounds.Top > 0) then
  begin
    ContentBounds.Bottom := Max(ContentBounds.Bottom, 2 * ClientHeight - FKBBounds.Top);
  end;
end;

constructor TfrmBaseForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  vsVKScrollBox.OnCalcContentBounds := CalcContentBoundsProc;
end;

procedure TfrmBaseForm.FormFocusChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UpdateKBBounds;
end;

procedure TfrmBaseForm.FormVirtualKeyboardHidden(Sender: TObject; KeyboardVisible: Boolean; const Bounds: TRect);
begin
  FKBBounds.Create(0, 0, 0, 0);
  FNeedOffset := False;
  RestorePosition;
end;

procedure TfrmBaseForm.FormVirtualKeyboardShown(Sender: TObject; KeyboardVisible: Boolean; const Bounds: TRect);
begin
  FKBBounds := TRectF.Create(Bounds);
  FKBBounds.TopLeft := ScreenToClient(FKBBounds.TopLeft);
  FKBBounds.BottomRight := ScreenToClient(FKBBounds.BottomRight);
  UpdateKBBounds;
end;

procedure TfrmBaseForm.RestorePosition;
begin
  vsVKScrollBox.ViewportPosition := PointF(vsVKScrollBox.ViewportPosition.X, 0);
  lyVKMain.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
  vsVKScrollBox.RealignContent;
end;

procedure TfrmBaseForm.UpdateKBBounds;
var
  LFocused: TControl;
  LFocusRect: TRectF;
begin
  FNeedOffset := False;
  if Assigned(Focused) then
  begin
    LFocused := TControl(Focused.GetObject);
    LFocusRect := LFocused.AbsoluteRect;
    LFocusRect.Offset(vsVKScrollBox.ViewportPosition);
    if (LFocusRect.IntersectsWith(TRectF.Create(FKBBounds))) and (LFocusRect.Bottom > FKBBounds.Top) then
    begin
      FNeedOffset := True;
      lyVKMain.Align := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
      vsVKScrollBox.RealignContent;
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      vsVKScrollBox.ViewportPosition := PointF(vsVKScrollBox.ViewportPosition.X, LFocusRect.Bottom - FKBBounds.Top);
    end;
  end;
  if not FNeedOffset then
    RestorePosition;
end;

end.
```